# Create custom url wagtail

Tags: django, url, wagtail, wagtail-pageurl

I have a site that I've structured like so:

Top Page: Animals
Subpage: Cat
Subpage: Dog

Top Page: Cat
Subpage: Food

Top Page: Dog
Subpage: Food

That way, a user can go to site/animals or site/cat. Animals is high-level info, Cat and Dog are more detailed parts of the site.

**What I want to do:** 
Occasionally, I want to be able to reuse pages from Animals and use them in Cat or Dog. But I don't want the url to switch from one section to another.

Example: If the user is under Animal, and they click a food article, the url should be:
`animals/cats/food_article`

If they click on that same article under cats, the url should look like:
`cats/food_article`

**What I've tried:**
I've tried using `RoutableRouteMixin`. But that works for subpages, not for pages at the same level.

I tried overwriting the `get_url_parts` method for the article models. But then I got 404 errors because the pages didn't actually exist at the url I created.

Can this be achieved in Wagtail? Or is there a Django solution I can use with Wagtail?

Answer (score 1):

You could create IncludePage as below and use it to present the same content under a different url.

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import PageChooserPanel
from django.http import Http404


class IncludePage(Page):
    page  = models.ForeignKey('wagtailcore.Page',
                              null=True, blank=True,
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                              related_name='+')

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
              PageChooserPanel('page'),
             ]

    def get_template(self, *args, **kwargs):
        page = self.page.specific
        if type(page) == IncludePage:
            raise Http404("Avoid recursion")
        return page.get_template(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context(self, *args, **kwargs):
        page = self.page.specific
        if type(page) == IncludePage:
            raise Http404("Avoid recursion")
        return page.get_context(*args, **kwargs)
```

> Note however this won't work for pages with customized serve functions
>   (e.g. pages using RoutableRouteMixin).  For those you would have to
>   duplicate the serve functionality across in the IncludePage to match. 
>   But depending on your website this might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

### Potential Approach

- Without major customisation, you will need to add a separate Page model for your articles, these can be added under the root page and then just not shown by default (including hidden from any menu setup you have).
- Then create a [modelcluster](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/pages/panels.html#inline-panels) that will be the relation between your animal pages (cat, dog) and your Article pages.
- Finally, override the Animal page's `get_children` method which is on each `Page` and comes from [`django-treebeard`](https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#treebeard.models.Node.get_children). This method is used by the routing logic to determine if a page is a child of another (when a URL is read).
- Once you create a few `AnimalPage`s, then create an `ArticlePage` (e.g. Food Article), then go into the dog page AND cat page and link the food article to the page.
- At this point you will be able to access the food-article at 3 URLs; `http://localhost:8000/food-article/`, `http://localhost:8000/animals/cats/food-article/` and `http://localhost:8000/animals/dogs/food-article/`.
- You can make the original food-article URL not work a few different ways, but the simplest way would be to put all `ArticlePage`s under their own parent page and then use routablemixin to make that page not show any sub-urls.

  - Note: If you put all articles under their own subpage (e.g. `ArticlesPage`, this should still work as it only checks the 'last' section of the URL). I have not tested this though.

### Example Code

```py
from django.db import models

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel

from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import (
    InlinePanel,
    PageChooserPanel,
)

from wagtail.core.models import Orderable, Page

class ArticlePage(Page):
    # Articles will be available to link to any other AnimalPage and content shared

    content_panels = Page.content_panels

    subpage_types = [] # no sub-pages allowed

class RelatedArticle(models.Model):
    # http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.7.1/reference/pages/panels.html#inline-panels
    article_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )

    panels = [
        PageChooserPanel('article_page', 'base.ArticlePage')
    ]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ArticlePageRelatedPages(Orderable, RelatedArticle):
    page = ParentalKey(
        'base.AnimalPage',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='related_articles'
    )

class AnimalsPage(Page):
    # This is our root animals page

    content_panels = Page.content_panels

    subpage_types = ['AnimalPage']


class AnimalPage(Page):

    def get_articles(self):
        # returns a queryset (not a list) of all Pages that are linked articles
        return Page.objects.filter(id__in=[
            r.article_page.pk for r in self.related_articles.all()
        ])

    def get_children(self):
        # override the method from django-treebeard
        # can be used in the template or wherever needed for 'children'
        # this method is also used when attempting to find child urls
        sub_pages = super().get_children()
        articles = self.get_articles()
        return articles | sub_pages # merges the two querysets for the 'or' operator

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        InlinePanel('related_articles', label='Related Articles'),
    ]

    subpage_types = [] # no sub-pages allowed
```